# How to set property injection with structure map?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, structuremap

I've got a MVC attribute that I need to use property injection vs constructor injection.  I'm using structure map to do the injection via an xml config.  The property never gets set, anyone see what I'm doing wrong?  thanks

```
 public class RequirePermissionAttribute: AuthorizeAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    #region Fields

    private readonly IPermissionService _permissionService;

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    [SetterProperty]
    public IPermissionService PermissionService
    {
        get
        { 
            return _permissionService; 
        }
        set
        {
            value = _permissionService;
        }
    }
```

....

Config file

```
<DefaultInstance PluggedType="Service.Permissions.PermissionService,Service" PluginType="Service.Permissions.IPermissionService,Service" Scope="HttpContext" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that `RequirePermissionAttribute` **is not resolved by StructureMap so it can set your property**. Attributes are compile time so you have to take additional steps to enable this.

I don't know if you're using a ControllerFactory or a DependencyResolver to enable the DI but with a ControllerFactory I used to supply an implementation of `ActionInvoker` property.

you can find some informations here : http://www.jeremyskinner.co.uk/2008/11/08/dependency-injection-with-aspnet-mvc-action-filters/. It's old but still applicable.